# Backdating issues after SonarQube upgrade

Tags: sonarqube

We have migrated from SonarQube5.5 to SonarQube 6.7.2LTS.

Upon the first analysis using the new version, projects started showing new issues based on overall rules improvements. While this is interesting, that makes the Quality Gate fail as part of our CI/CD pipelines.

Looking at the following page:
https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarqube-6-3-in-screenshots

... we can see that there is some kind of issue backdating overhead, which looks broken for that specific scenario.

Any recommendation or workaround as for not making everything red for all projects. We still want to keep that technical debt visible and not necessarily hide it using Wont't fixes of False Positives.

Thank you

Comment: To be clear, are the issues actually backdated? FYI, here's the [relevant topic](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-766). Does your situation match?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam no, they are not. Issues are dated just like if they were newly injected in the code by the developers. Looking at the JIRA ticket, this is exactly our situation. We've updated SQ to a newer version (that includes better implementations in the rules), which brings new debt to the table. I see that the ticket is closed, but is there any concrete solution from the customer perspective (manual intervention on our side)? 

We plan on updating to 6.7.3LTS this week. Will it fix that issue?

Comment: You started from SQ5.5, which means you went _through_ 5.6. Did you perform analyses on 5.6 before upgrading to 6.7.2?

Comment: No I didn't. I went from 5.5 to 5.6.7LTS, and immediately jumped to 6.7.2LTS. Followed the migration guide to the letter. Thank you!

Comment: I just gave a try and everything is working fine. Could you please provide the result of the WS http://<your SQ server>/api/plugins/installed. I wonder what is the value of `updatedAt` fields. Also, can you give the ruleKey of a few issues that are not correctly backdated on your side? It might be more appropriate to continue the investigation on the SonarQube Google group.